# Unknown table 'table' in field list on referencing temporary table inside a trigger

Tags: mysql, trigger, temporary-tables

I am creating a trigger `BEFORE INSERT` that checks a record from another table to see if it exists, otherwise signal `sqlstate`. The trigger definition shown below

```
DELIMITER //
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS pob_exists_barang_kode//
CREATE TRIGGER pob_exists_barang_kode BEFORE INSERT
ON `PURCHASE_ORDER_BARANG` FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    declare msg varchar(128);
    CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE kode_barang_tbl 
    SELECT ven.`KODE_BARANG`  as kode_barang
    FroM  (
            SELECT po.`REQ_VENDOR_ID` as rvid
            FROM `PURCHASE_ORDER` po,
                 `PURCHASE_ORDER_BARANG` pob
            WHERE NEW.`PURCHASE_ORDER_ID` = po.`ID`
          ) `asdf`,
          `VENDOR_BARANG` ven
    WHERE ven.`VENDOR_ID` = asdf.rvid;
    
    CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE dummy1
    SELECT po.`REQ_VENDOR_ID` as rvid
            FROM `PURCHASE_ORDER` po,
                 `PURCHASE_ORDER_BARANG` pob
            WHERE NEW.`PURCHASE_ORDER_ID` = po.`ID`;
    
    IF NEW.barang_kode not in (kode_barang_tbl.kode_barang) THEN 
        set msg = concat('Kesalahan! Tidak ada kode barang ', 
                          cast(new.barang_kode as char), 
                          ' pada vendor id ', 
                          cast(dummy1.rvid as char)
                        );
        signal sqlstate '45000' set message_text = msg;
    END IF;
    
    DROP TEMPORARY TABLE dummy1;
    DROP TEMPORARY TABLE kode_barang_tbl;
END;//

DELIMITER ;
```

Trigger created fine, so I ran this script below to test if the trigger works:

```
insert into `PURCHASE_ORDER_BARANG` values ('po2', '1', 5135, null);
```

but it returns an error message

```
Error Code: 1109. Unknown table 'kode_barang_tbl' in field list
```

Executing the part of the statement works as expected:

```
SELECT ven.`KODE_BARANG`  as kode_barang
    FroM  (
            SELECT po.`REQ_VENDOR_ID` as rvid
            FROM `PURCHASE_ORDER` po,
                 `PURCHASE_ORDER_BARANG` pob
            WHERE po.`ID` = 'po2'
          ) `asdf`,
          `VENDOR_BARANG` ven
    WHERE ven.`VENDOR_ID` = asdf.rvid;
```

I'm not really sure which line causes the error, but I am sure I have created the temporary tables and the trigger correctly. I also have no table `kode_barang_tbl` inside the database except in this trigger. Am I missing something? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: The problematic row is `IF NEW.barang_kode not in (kode_barang_tbl.kode_barang) THEN`. You must use `IF NEW.barang_kode not in (SELECT kode_barang FROM kode_barang_tbl) THEN`

Comment: PS. Your code is strange... for example, the subquery `asdf` by fact only checks does at least one row with `ID = 'po2'` exists in `PURCHASE_ORDER`. And by fact temporary tables not needed at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As akina aleready noted you don't need any temp tables

> ```
> CREATE TABLE PURCHASE_ORDER(id int ,REQ_VENDOR_ID varchar(50) )
> ```

> ```
> INSERT INTO PURCHASE_ORDER VALUES (1,'or123')
> ```

> ```
> CREATE TABLE PURCHASE_ORDER_BARANG (barang_kode  varchar(50),PURCHASE_ORDER_ID int, id2 int,id3 int)
> ```

> ```
> CREATE TABLe VENDOR_BARANG (id int, `VENDOR_ID` varchar(50),KODE_BARANG varchar(50))
> ```

> ```
> INSERT INTO VENDOR_BARANG values (1,'or123','or123')
> ```

> ```
> CREATE TRIGGER pob_exists_barang_kode BEFORE INSERT
> ON `PURCHASE_ORDER_BARANG` FOR EACH ROW
> BEGIN
>     declare msg varchar(128);
>
>      IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
>     FroM  (
>             SELECT po.`REQ_VENDOR_ID` as rvid
>             FROM `PURCHASE_ORDER` po INNER JOIN
>                  `PURCHASE_ORDER_BARANG` pob
>             WHERE NEW.`PURCHASE_ORDER_ID` = po.`ID`
>           ) `asdf` INNER JOIN 
>           `VENDOR_BARANG` ven ON
>      ven.`VENDOR_ID` = asdf.rvid 
>     WHERE NEW.barang_kode = ven.`KODE_BARANG`) then
>         SELECT po.`REQ_VENDOR_ID` INTO @rvid
>             FROM `PURCHASE_ORDER` po,
>                  `PURCHASE_ORDER_BARANG` pob
>             WHERE NEW.`PURCHASE_ORDER_ID` = po.`ID`;
>             
>         set msg = concat('Kesalahan! Tidak ada kode barang ', 
>                           cast(new.barang_kode as char), 
>                           ' pada vendor id ', 
>                           cast(COALESCE(@rvid,-1) as char)
>                         );
>         signal sqlstate '45000' set message_text = msg;
>     END IF;
>     
> END
> ```

> ```
> insert into `PURCHASE_ORDER_BARANG` values ('po2', '1', 5135, null);
> ```
>
> ```
> Kesalahan! Tidak ada kode barang po2 pada vendor id -1
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=96ce66e3d1918dfc53b8f4604f5f3dbb)*

Answer (score 0):

The solution is now found by Akina, I made a mistake on `IF NEW.barang_kode not in (kode_barang_tbl.kode_barang) THEN` which should be `IF NEW.barang_kode not in (SELECT kode_barang FROM kode_barang_tbl) THEN`. I also made changes to my script which makes the same error on `cast(dummy1.rvid as char)`. So here's my full script in the end. Thanks to Akina.

```
DELIMITER //
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS pob_exists_barang_kode//
CREATE TRIGGER pob_exists_barang_kode BEFORE INSERT
ON `PURCHASE_ORDER_BARANG` FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    declare msg varchar(128);
    CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE kode_barang_tbl 
    SELECT ven.`KODE_BARANG` as kode_barang
    FroM  (
            SELECT po.`REQ_VENDOR_ID` as rvid
            FROM `PURCHASE_ORDER` po
            WHERE NEW.`PURCHASE_ORDER_ID` = po.`ID`
          ) `asdf`,
          `VENDOR_BARANG` ven
    WHERE ven.`VENDOR_ID` = asdf.rvid;
    
    SELECT po.`REQ_VENDOR_ID` as rvid
            FROM `PURCHASE_ORDER` po
            WHERE NEW.`PURCHASE_ORDER_ID` = po.`ID` INTO @rvid;
    
    
    IF NEW.barang_kode not in (SELECT kode_barang FROM kode_barang_tbl) THEN 
        set @errmsg = concat('Kesalahan! Tidak ada kode barang ', 
                          cast(new.barang_kode as char), 
                          ' pada vendor id ', 
                          cast(@rvid as char)
                        );
            DROP TEMPORARY TABLE kode_barang_tbl;
        signal sqlstate '45000' set message_text = @errmsg;
    END IF;
    
    DROP TEMPORARY TABLE kode_barang_tbl;
END;//

DELIMITER ;
```